# Разный уровень доступа в интернет для разных хостов в локальной сети

Tags: linux, ubuntu, сеть, firewall, vlan

В качестве рутера я использую `Ubuntu 16.04` с 2 сетевыми картами. Текущая конфигурация очень простая - *белый* `IPv4` на внешнем интерфейсе и `NAT` силами `ufw` на внутреннем. В качестве `DHCP` и кэширующего `DNS` сервера я использую `dnsmasq`. Мой *ethernet* свитч поддерживает `VLAN`, но сейчас эта функция выключена.

Я часто подключаю к локальной сети новые устройства (новые виртуальные машины) и по умолчанию все они сразу получают доступ в интернет, что мне не очень нравится.

Я хочу поменять конфигурацию таким образом, чтобы `NAT` работал только для хостов из *белого* списка, а все остальные имели доступ к локальным ресурсам, но не к интернету.

Каким образом это лучше/легче всего сделать? Желательно не меняя `ufw` и `dnsmasq` на их аналоги (так как с этими программами я уже частично разобралась)

Пока у меня есть следущие идеи:

1. настроить разные `dhcp` диапазоны и по умолчанию назначать неправильный `gateway`
2. назначить *внутренней* сетевой карте несколько `IP` адресов из разных подсетей и делать `NAT` только для одной подсети
3. включить поддержку `VLAN` на свитче и каким-то образом использовать эту функциональность (пока не знаю как, просто я давно собиралась разобраться с `VLAN`)

Comment: Лучше изучить [iptables](http://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/iptables/) Достаточно будет правил фильтрации трафика + согласованную работу DHCP. Если захочется более изощрённых методов, можно будет связать правила iptables с каким либо модулем авторизации, например посредством скриптов.

Comment: Способ-1 неправильный gateway привёдет к росту паразитного трафика и возможно заторможенности некоторых приложений на клиентах. Способ-2 затруднит общение между машинами в одном физическом сетевом сегменте, межсетевой трафик пойдёт через роутер. Спопоб-3 можно настроить VLAN + тегирование трафика, из одной сетевой получиться несколько, но сложность настройки и сопровождения по моему не оправдывает.

Comment: За `ufw` не скажу, могу сказать за `shorewall`. Я с помощью него и старого компа колхозил раздачу интернета для нескольких мелких фирм в одном здании. Если бы не убитое железо - он бы до сих пор пахал (хотя 5 лет всё-таки отработал).

Comment: способ 2,  зачем из разных подсетей? Из одной, но nat делать только для пакетов приходящих на один из адресов. Правда не надёжно, пользователь может на своём компе поменять таблицу маршрутизации.

Answer (score 1):

настраивали *nat* («маскарадинг») вы, вероятно, по [этой](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/firewall.html#ip-masquerading) инструкции.

тогда строку в `/etc/ufw/before.rules`:

```
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

надо заменить на две:

```
-A POSTROUTING -s список -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -j DROP
```

где `список` — это разделённый запятыми список «белых» ip-адресов вида:

```
192.168.0.100,192.168.0.101,192.168.0.103
```

и т.д. и т.п.